# SSIS how to set a null identifier for a flat file source?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Using SSIS, I am trying to import a csv file that uses

> \N

to identify null values.
Is there any way in ssis I can configure the data source to recognise these as nulls, instead of a string "\N".

I know I could use a data conversion to do this, but using the source would be more elegant if possible!

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using a data conversion task, you could use a derived column task to take that value and implement an expression so that when your value is /N you can actually return **null** instead for that column.

Expression approximately

```
[MyCol] == "\\N" ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 50) : [MyCol]
```

Comment: billinkc! You're the real MVP here. Thanks for filling this expression in! Hopeflly Neil P will be able to get up and running with that!